# Does a class implement org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConverter to convert from/to XML

Tags: xml, spring, jms, converters

Does a class implement org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConverter to convert from/to XML, like MappingJackson2MessageConverter converts from/to JSON ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes ofcourse you can, implement the MessageConverter interface and provide your own implementation to the methods fromMessage() and toMessage().

```
package com.springmvc.custom.converter;

import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageHeaders;
import org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConverter;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageBuilder;

public class CustomPayloadConverter implements MessageConverter{

    @Override
    public Object fromMessage(Message<?> message, Class<?> targetClass) {
         Object payLoad = message.getPayload();
         //write your logic here.
         return payLoad;
    }

    @Override
    public Message<?> toMessage(Object payload, MessageHeaders headers) {
        // write your logic.
        return MessageBuilder.withPayload(payload).copyHeaders(headers).build();
    }
 }
```